# How to use .env file in smarty?

Tags: php, environment-variables, smarty3, smarty2

I am new to smarty template. My all database settings are in /inc/settings/DSOPSettings.local.php but Every time I get pull from git for changes It overrides.

I have tried to set .env file in smarty template project root tried to get env variables in DSOPSettings.local.php file but It's not working for me.

My .env file :

```
DB_WRITE_HOST=localhost
DB_WRITE_USER=root
DB_WRITE_PASS=test
DB_WRITE_DBASE_DEV=storytalk
```

My DSOPSettings.local.php :

```
define('DB_WRITE_HOST', env('DB_WRITE_HOST'));
define('DB_WRITE_USER', env('DB_WRITE_USER'));
define('DB_WRITE_PASS', env('DB_WRITE_PASS'));
define('DB_WRITE_DBASE_DEV', env('DB_WRITE_DBASE_DEV'));
```

I have also tried to get env variables as below but not working.

```
define('DB_WRITE_HOST', getenv('DB_WRITE_HOST'));
define('DB_WRITE_USER', getenv('DB_WRITE_USER'));
define('DB_WRITE_PASS', getenv('DB_WRITE_PASS')));
define('DB_WRITE_DBASE_DEV', getenv('DB_WRITE_DBASE_DEV'));
```

How can I make this working?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how are you loading the .env file?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have created .env file in project root.

Comment: A smarty template isn't PHP so it can't access PHP variables/functions/constants unless you specifically pass them to template or create a template function where you can get them.. Please show us how you're loading the env file, how you pass them to the template and how you're trying to use the data in the templates.

Comment: it won't magically load itself

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't want to use them in template file. I want to use them in /inc/settings/DSOPSettings.local.php file as I have displayed above.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How to load .env file in smarty?

Comment: If you _"don't want to use them in template file"_, then your title _"How to use .env file in smarty template?"_ is very misleading. What do you then mean by "load .env file in smarty"? If you just want to load them in a PHP file, where does Smarty come into play? The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am searching a way to load env in smarty. I found it and implemented as follow.

.env

```
DB_WRITE_USER=root
DB_WRITE_PASS=test
DB_WRITE_DBASE_DEV=storytalk
```

I have created one class to load all .env variables. Env.php

```
<?php
namespace EnvironmentSettings;
class Env
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    
    public function load($path)
    {
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('%s does not exist', $path));
        }
        
        if (!is_readable($path)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('%s file is not readable', $this->path));
        }

        $lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {

            if (strpos(trim($line), '#') === 0) {
                continue;
            }

            list($name, $value) = explode('=', $line, 2);
            $name = trim($name);
            $value = trim($value);

            if (!array_key_exists($name, $_SERVER) && !array_key_exists($name, $_ENV)) {
                putenv(sprintf('%s=%s', $name, $value));
                $_ENV[$name] = $value;
                $_SERVER[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Load it in any file as follow :

```
$env = new EnvironmentSettings\Env();
$env->load(INSTALLED_ROOT_PATH.INSTALLED_PATH."/.env");
```

Now use it with getenv() function. Ex. `getenv('DB_WRITE_USER')`